# Add text for under character limit

Tags: excel, vba

Just wondering if this is possible, and how I would go about doing it... I'm not sure if I can use conditional formatting, or if it requires VBA, or what.

I have a vlookup that I split coding for, but it only works when they include ".000000.00000.0000.0000" at the end. How would I go about adding ".000000.00000.0000.0000" when the character limit is under 46 for that cell? The coding will always be 46 characters when the zeroes are included, so anything under is invalid.

Comment: You can probably use `Left()` or something. Could you post some sample data?

Comment: usually the formula should be adjusted to the input, not the other way around

Comment: If that was the lookup value (and it was in, for instance, cell A1) then you can just change `VLOOKUP(A1, ...)` to `VLOOKUP(A1&IF(LEN(A1)<46,".000000.00000.0000.0000",""), ...)`

Comment: It looks like I don't need .000000.00000.0000.0000. I figured the rest out using the information provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use =IF(LEN(A2) < 23, "0" & LEFT(A2,15),LEFT(A2,16)) to truncate what I needed and add leading zeroes if not included to have the end result do what I needed without all of the zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Sub test()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim text As String

    For i = 1 To 32767
         text = text & "a"
    Next

    text = text & "end"
    Range("A1").Value = text
    '"end" will be lost

  End Sub
```